# NSPredicate in Core Data Fetch for Mode in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate

I would like to search a core data entity of locations for the coordinates that occur most often.  In statistics, this would correspond to the *mode* or most common value.

NSPredicate lets you use the words max or min.

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "coordinate == max(coordinate)")
```

Is there an equivalent for mode as in:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "coordinate == mode(coordinate)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no.

Predicate syntax is like a limited version of SQL. The documentation shows that `mode` isn’t part of the syntax.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html

Or expanding on that you can use `KVC Collection Operators` for some simple operations (max/min/avg…)

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/CollectionOperators.html

You’ll need to bake your own algorithm for this.

This article suggests something you might explore.

https://nshipster.com/kvc-collection-operators/

Comment: The article looks promising.  Do you think I do a count of all the unique values and then sort them

Comment: The technique in the NSHipster article is just syntax sugar. You’ll need to do the work to pick the most common value range according to your spec. A coordinate is a 2 or 3 dimension point with floating point values. You want to find the box/volume  with the most points inside it.

Comment: Found some more ideas here http://www.cimgf.com/2015/06/25/core-data-and-aggregate-fetches-in-swift/